# Inherit from Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, mongodb-.net-driver

```
public class BsonObjectAttribute: BsonRepresentationAttribute
{
    public BsonObjectAttribute(BsonType representation)
    {
        base(representation);
    }
}
```

I am trying to create an attribute from `BsonRepresentationAttribute`. But i am getting two compilation errors as follow

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'representation' of BsonRepresentationAttribute.BsonRepresentationAttribute(BsonType)

and

> Use of keyword 'base' is not valid in this context

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't attribute-specific - you're just not using the right syntax to chain from one constructor to a base constructor. It should be:

```
public BsonObjectAttribute(BsonType representation) : base(representation)
{
}
```

Comment: Careless mistake from my part

Comment: How does it feels getting answered by jon skeet?